# SaveAs() file in Application's folder from fileUpload in ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a `FileUpload` control in ASP.NET.

**C# Code**

```
if (FileUpldFile.HasFile)
{
   try
   {
      //saving the file
      FileUpldLicenceFileMOT.SaveAs("c:\\SaveDirectory" + FileUpldFile.FileName);

      //Getting the Path of saved file
      var pathMot = @"c:\\SaveDirectory" + FileUpldFile.FileName;

      //Getting File Extension
      var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(pathMot).Substring(1);
      ViewState["fileExtension_MOT"] = fileExtension;
     .....
```

Here I want to save the file in my application's folder, my application folder's structure is like this:

```
--> Root Folder
   --> Documents
      --> sampleFileFromFileUpload.png
```

**Question:** how can I save the file using `SaveAs()` in the application's internal folder (i.e: `Root Folder > Documents`) from a `FileUpload` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (FileUpldFile.HasFile)
            {
            string savelocation=Server.MapPath("~/Documents/");
                try
                {
                    //saving the file
                    FileUpldLicenceFileMOT.SaveAs(savelocation + FileUpldFile.FileName);
    ...
```

Use Server.MapPath() to get the absolute path by passing in a path relative to the site root. Make sure that your server has the correct permissions to access the folder you're saving to.